# Using MultiActionController

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Currently i am using paging on my page which uses `MultiActionController` which displays a jsp page perfectly , on the same page now i want to validate a simple textfield (`input/form:input`) also want to retrieve name and id from a dropdown(`Select option`) once a link is clicked. Simple !!

Two questions

1. Can i use a class implements Validator? and inject it same way as simpleformcontroller in config or some other way within the controller? How? example please?
2. Can i use java bean in jsp  -> i always get error of binding, how to indicated controller to use this bean? i have have passed as argument to my method add and also tried overriding newCommandObject

`Controller.java`

```
public ModelAndView add(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,  Person person) throws Exception { 

         return new ModelAndView("userpage"); 
    } 

@Override 
    protected Object newCommandObject(Class clazz) 
    throws Exception {

         return new Person();
}
```

Comment: What version of Spring-MVC are you using? I suggest you use a JSR-303 validator which can be obtained from www.hibernate.org but this requires a fresh version of Spring.

Comment: I second the JSR 303 validator. But since you are using Spring 3 you might want to reconsider using MultiActionController. The old Controller zoo has a more flexible successor where you can use any class as a controller by using a new set of annotations. Search for annotations Controller and Valid.

Answer (score 0):

I will do something like below in Spring version > 2.5

```
@Controller
public class YourController
{
    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    private final String yourInputJsp = "yourInputJsp";

    private final String yourInputJspSuccess = "yourInputJspSuccess";

    private YourService yourService;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("yourFormValidator")
    private YourFormValidator validator;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/yourRequest.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String referenceData(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception 
    {
        yourService = new YourServiceImpl(ContextHandler.getWebAppContext(request));
        YourFormData yourFormData = new YourFormData();

        model.addAttribute("yourFormData", yourFormData);

        return yourInputJsp;
    }

    @InitBinder()
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) throws Exception {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new StringMultipartFileEditor());
    }

        @RequestMapping(value="/yourRequest.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String process(@ModelAttribute("yourFormData") YourFormData yourFormData, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status, HttpServletRequest request)
        {
            String mav = yourInputJsp;
            validator.validate(yourFormData, result);

            if(!result.hasErrors())
            {
                //Some business logic

                mav = "redirect:yourInputJspSuccess.htm";
                status.setComplete();
            }

            return mav;
    }
}
```